# How to enable IntelliSense and indexer at the same time in typescript?

Tags: typescript, type-definition

For example, I have an object:

```js
const obj = {
  a: (valueA: string) => true;
  b: (valueB: string) => false;
  c: (valueC: string) => false;
};
```

You see all properties in this object have same type (`(value: string) => boolean`). Now I want it to have IntelliSense which makes follows possible:

1. Display `a`, `b`, `c` after I typed `obj.`;
2. Limit its type when I try to add a property into `obj`.

I tried **indexer**:

```js
const obj: Record<string, ((value: string) => boolean)> = {
  a: (valueA: string) => true;
  b: (valueB: string) => false;
  c: (valueC: string) => false;
};
```

But now target 1 won't happen, if I don't use indexer, I cannot achieve target 2.

Comment: One word, I want to have an object that all properties in it have the same type, but I also need the IntelliSense of properties already defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable inference is either all or nothing, you either let typescript infer the type or you specify the type yourself.

You can only do this with a helper function:

```
function makeFunctionsMap<T extends Record<string, ((value: string) => boolean)>>(o: T) { return o; }
const obj = makeFunctionsMap({
  a: (valueA: string) => true,
  b: (valueB: string) => false,
  c: (valueC: string) => false,
})
obj.a;
obj.d // Error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYGsCmAxc15gDOAsqgA4A8AKopgB5SZgAmhiASphHAE7MWEoPGGADmAGkQAKKQDdUAGxCYAXIkHCxASkQBeAHyIARnDgLMqMFv36pcNVR0BvRD0xQQPJHADciAL4AUNxEUIhwRgBWeigYOHiwCCTkUk6BiIioanKKygCCahoiojoGiELK4unG2fJKmABChULFpYbAioSYVRkQtbmYAMLNmiV67Z3dgf5agRGRAHSoPnNRC8yIAPSbiACiPDy8QA)

You can also inline the function if you want to make it shorter and more unreadable ([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGAKAPAFRgUwA8o8wATCGAJT1ACdTNpaBLMAcwBoN0A3AQwA2AVzwAuGE1ZsAlKgB8MeCBAC8fMNLlz0IcdlkoFIaegDeAKBgw+43oJEBBcZPYGFUWiI6XFt-sLwAIWcPKTcYADNBCDxvK2A-ezwAYRCWV3lI6NjzAF9pcwREADo+AG5CpGLSGAB6WpgAUVpaEFogA))